# Security and SQL injection in Sql Server with ASP membership

Tags: asp.net, security, sql-injection

I'm implementing ASP MVC with membership. The site is hosted in Azure cloud.

What are some defensive steps to prevent

1. Sql Injection brute force attacks
2. how can I prevent/lockout user from an IP based on attempts

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for first question.
You have to storage some useful data in "Session[data]" and don't sent it from client side.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                String ContractID_string = Session["ContractID"].ToString();
                if(ContractID_string!="0")
```

Also don't use some string input values from client in linq or sqlQuery without check.

The best way use

in control

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _SaveMail(Email_Options Mail)
```

in view

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SaveMail", "Contract", Model,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "Email_Options",
            OnFailure = "alert('errr')",
            OnSuccess = "DeleteErrorMessage('#Form_"+ViewBag.Contract_part+"')"
        }, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Form_"+ViewBag.Contract_part}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <table id="Email_Options">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Email, new { style = "font-size:1.05em;" })</th>
                    <th> 
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ContractID)
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Email)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Email)
                        <button style="font-size:1em; margin:0px; padding:0;" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.SendToEmail, new { @class = "checkbox" })</th>
                    <th>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.SendToEmail)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.SentToHome, new { @class = "checkbox" })</th>
                    <th>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.SentToHome)</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Print, new { @class = "checkbox" })</th>
                    <th>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Print)</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```